# Bitmap to byte[] to SQL and backwards

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, bitmap

I'm creating app in which you can add item which contains image and some data, after that item's data is stored in SQLite Data Base. The way I want to do this is choose image from gallery from android device, convert it to byte[] so I can store it as Blob in SQLiteDataBase. To do that I have to compress bitmap to byte[] and it takes a lot of memory so I tried to do that as AsyncTask. **Now my threat is that when I try to retrive byte[] of image from database and decode it to Bitmap it takes a lot of memory and my listview which displays data is very laggy, even crashing the app**. Do you have any idea how can I make it work better?
Here is some code of my app.

```
public class CompressImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, byte[]> {

@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmaps[0].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Code for inserting data about specific item:

```
private void insertFlower() {
    CompressImage compressImage = new CompressImage();

    String name = mFlowerName.getText().toString().trim();
    String price = mFlowerPrice.getText().toString().trim();
    String quantity = mFlowerQuantity.getText().toString().trim();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_PRICE, price);
    contentValues.put(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_TYPE, mType);
    contentValues.put(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_QUANTITY, quantity);
    contentValues.put(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_IMAGE, compressImage.doInBackground(bitmap));

    getContentResolver().insert(FlowersEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
}
```

**And here come the main problem when I resolve data from database and it takes so long...**

```
public class FlowersCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public FlowersCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flowers_name);
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flowers_price);
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flowers_quantity);
    ImageView imageImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flowers_image);

    String nameFromDb = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_NAME));
    String priceFromDb = String.valueOf(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_PRICE)));
    String quantityFromDb = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_QUANTITY)));
    byte[] byteFromDb = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(FlowersEntry.COLUMN_FLOWER_IMAGE));

    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteFromDb, 0, byteFromDb.length);


    nameTextView.setText(nameFromDb);
    priceTextView.setText(priceFromDb);
    quantityTextView.setText(quantityFromDb);
    Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(bitmapImage).into(imageImageView);

}
```

Comment: what is the average size of your bitmaps?

Comment: I guess what pskink is alluding to is that storing images in the database can be problematic due to their size and IO overheads (compounded by poor use of cacheing) e.g. A Cursor Window is limited to 2M. It is considered better practice to store the path to the image in the database, extract that and to then retrieve the actual image from it's path.

Comment: @MikeT in general i couldnt agree more but: https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html and/or https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html

Comment: @pskink I checked for bitmapImage.getByteCount() after decoding it from database and it equals to 48794880 what is 46,5MB if I'm getting it right, but I don't know why is that if I load pictures from my phone's gallery and photos weight 3,50MB average.

Comment: Anyway I think I will try @MikeT idea about storing path in database.

Comment: then see two links I posted above

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line after using the bitmapImage in bindView.

```
bitmapImage.recycle();
```

Comment: I think Glide Library solves this problem automaticlly.